# Laravel Umlaute ORM - Problems with saving

Tags: php, laravel, sqlsrv

I receive some "Umlaute" - like "ä,ü,ö) from an webservice, and i have problems with utf-8 here. When ill store them into my database, it shown like:

```
..rsit&#228;t
```

Ok, so checked about utf-8 encoding, but when ill try to echo the value before saving it, its shown correct with all the Umlaute in utf-8.

My database is utf-8 too (another tables from different services store utf-8 without any problems). The only thing whats different here is, that i am storing it in an transaction.

```
echo $laststop; // Fine with all the Umlaute

$Route = new BusRoute();
$Route->last_stop = $laststop; // if i set this to something like that: "Tüüt" as String, its correct in DB too
$Route->save();
```

// wrong in database

```
// database.php
'dev_db' => [
        'driver'   => 'sqlsrv',
        'charset'  => 'utf8',
        'prefix'   => '',
    ],

// model.php

class BusRoute extends Model
{
    protected $connection = 'db_dev';

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
     protected $table = 'bus_routes';

 }
```

Edit: Checked my Model "BusRoute.php" - saved with UTF-8 Encoding.

Its strange - because i read multiple webservices - and only got here that problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The webservice delivers you data with certain characters encoded to their corresponding html entites. Use html_entity_decode() to convert them back to single characters before storing the data in your database.

```
$decoded_string = html_entity_decode('..rsit&#228;t');
```

This will convert `&#228;` back to `ä`.

Comment: Ah that was easy. The thing ive not checked (because when ill show it in my Browser, he shows me the correct Umlaute (because of the encoding) - Thank you so much!

Comment: @derdida I was sure you verified it when you wrote `its shown correct with all the Umlaute in utf-8.` :)